# Sort Operation with Covering Index

Tags: sql-server

We have a query producing a Sort operation w/in the plan but we have a covering index:

[image]

I was under the impression that a covering index would help mitigate the need for a Sort operation.

Query plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=By-AXqg2K

The POSTAL_CODE table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[POSTAL_CODE](
    [PC_VALUE] [nvarchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [PC_CITY] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PC_SP_ABBREV] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [PC_COU_ABBREV] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [PC_LATITUDE] [real] NULL,
    [PC_LONGITUDE] [real] NULL,
    [PC_TZ_ID] [int] NULL,
    [PC_OBSERVES_DAYLIGHT] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [PC_COUNTY] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PC_DATE_INSERTED] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PC_DATE_UPDATED] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PC_STATUS] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [PC_ZON_ID] [int] NULL,
    [PC_AREA_CODE] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [PC_PREFERRED] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [PC_CLU_ID] [int] NULL,
    [PC_WORK_INDEX] [tinyint] NULL,
    [PC_WORK_MINS_DIFF] [smallint] NULL,
    [PC_LIS_COUNT] [smallint] NULL,
    [PC_WORK_MINS_AVG] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [POSTAL_CODE_POSTAL_CODE$PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PC_VALUE] ASC,
    [PC_COU_ABBREV] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: A covering index will only help avoid the sort if the index order after any seek predicates is the same order as you request for the `ORDER BY` - this won't be the case for `ORDER BY ((3958 * 3.1415926 * SQRT((PC_LATITUDE - 1) * (PC_LATITUDE - 1) + COS(PC_LATITUDE / 57.29578) * COS(1 / 57.29578) * (PC_LONGITUDE - 1) * (PC_LONGITUDE - 1)) / 180)) ASC`

Comment: Your query is sorting by expression results, not columns directly. A full scan and  sort will be required with this design.

Comment: It is difficult to read your query, but I see `PC_LATITUDE` appearing inside a function call to `SQRT()`, and therefore I'm not sure that you index would even be getting used here.

Comment: That index is of no use to the optimizer (for sorting), it's ordered on `PC_Value` for a start, but the ordering criteria is a function of the values which is not sargable in the same way a *where* criteria would not be sargable.

Comment: Have you looked at the Geography datatype? I'm not sure what your calculation is doing but assuming you are ordering by distance then likely it will be better supported there

Comment: No, I'm not aware of a GEOGRAPHY type. Th formula you see is the standard for determining distances in miles on most areas of middle Earth.

Comment: So you probably want to be looking at `STDistance` and spatial indexes. Though I haven't used these much myself either. Looks relevant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/query-spatial-data-for-nearest-neighbor?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Please only paste them in as text. Query plans can be shared via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan, a picture of the plan is next to useless for us

Comment: You could create a computed column on that calculation, then index it `PC (YourCalculation) INCLUDE (PC_VALUE)` then you will get no sort. You would need to use deterministic data types such as `decimal` rather than `real`. But I agree you should probably consider `geograohy` and a spatial index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for the server to use this index for your query, because the ordering criterion is a complex calculation, which means that the result is not going to be the same sort order as `PC_VALUE`.

One option is to create a computed column on that calculation, then index it

```sql
ALTER TABLE POSTAL_CODE
  ADD Distance AS (
    3958 *
    3.1415926 *
    SQRT(
        (PC_LATITUDE - 1) * (PC_LATITUDE - 1) +
        COS(PC_LATITUDE / 57.29578) *
        COS(1 / 57.29578) *
        (PC_LONGITUDE - 1) * (PC_LONGITUDE - 1)
    ) /
    180)
  PERSISTED;  -- must be persisted because it is an imprecise (float) value
    
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX ON POSTAL_CODE(Distance) INCLUDE (PC_VALUE);
```

Now you will get no sort, as shown [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e274df20695ebdb04faa31f89b87308f). The server can simply look at the query and say "We have an index on this value already, let's look up the first row in the index".

You can obviously also now refer to just that computed column:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1
  PC_VALUE
FROM POSTAL_CODE PC
ORDER BY Distance;
```

But I agree with commenters that you should probably consider `geography` and a spatial index instead.